# Visiting Istria region in June

Tags: public-transport, buses, ferries, croatia, venice

We will be leaving Venice June 27th to the region of Istria and we would like to know the best way to get there (ferry or bus) and we are wondering which is the best city to stay at to visit the region. We want to stay 3 or 4 days and after we will be travelling south in the Dalmatia region.

Comment: I have both hitchhiked and taken the ferry to Pula. Both of these were the 'best' considering my circumstances at the times.  The scenic route is by land and it would be a shame to miss Trieste if you haven't seen it. The cruise is 'best' if you're looking for a direct route to the tip of the peninsula.

Comment: We don't really do recommendations on TSE. What is `best` for you?

Comment: I've been to both Pula and Rovinj. Which I think are both very nice touristy cities, if you are into that.